# ASP Page directive inherits structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

Kind of a simple question, but I'm having trouble finding exactly the definition for this.
On an .aspx page, in the @Page directive, what is the exact definition/structure of the inherits tag? For example, if my sln was called ClassLibrary1, my .dll was called ClassLibrary1.dll, the classes namespace was Test1, and the class was called Test1Page, would it look like:

`Inherits="Test1.Test1Page,ClassLibrary1,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=f659cda3c5ffa92d"`

Or differently? Where does exactly each part go (other than the Public key)?

Comment: This is the Assembly-Qualified Name of the type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(converted from comment)

This is the Assembly-Qualified name of the Type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx

Comment: Ok this helps a good amount. Is there an easy way to grab this in a class library? Rather than a console application?

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean.

Comment: No worries, just confused myself and figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a uniform syntax known as "assembly qualified naming" in .NET and you can read about it here:

**[AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx)**